# Unawaited error in flutter with http package

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, http

```
 
import 'package:weather_app/models/constants.dart';
import 'package:weather_app/models/weather.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

dynamic weatherData(String location) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(searchWeatherAPI(key: Constants.API_KEY) + location);

    var response = await http.get(url); // this is line 30

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<Weather> weatherData = weatherFromJson("[${response.body}]");
      return weatherData;
    } else {
      print(response.body);
      return response.body;
    }
  }
```

when i run this code the app crashed and show me browser_client.dart
and this error apear in debug console

```
ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'see': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 30..

ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'only': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 30..

ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'unawaited': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 30..

ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'the': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 30..
```

i'm tried to use

```
try{}catch(e){}
```

but error still happen

my api must get city or country name and if exist return its weather data and if not exist return "No matching location found." and i'll make user insert this country or city name and must return message for him if exist or not

Answer (score 0):

I think your json to dart conversion gone wrong.you should try this-

```
 List<Weather> weatherData = 
 weatherFromJson(response.body);
```